# fscanf for text files in C

Tags: c, scanf

I have a file that

```
1   Toy Story   1995    01-Jan-1995 http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?Toy%20Story%20(1995)   Animation|Children's|Comedy 
2   GoldenEye   1995    01-Jan-1995 http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?GoldenEye%20(1995) Action|Adventure|Thriller
```

and the space between columns has written with tab
here's my code but ...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <unistd.h>

FILE *MovieF;
void addFileM();

struct Movies
{
   char MID[50];
   char MName[50];
   char MYear[50];
   char MDate[50];
   char MIMDB[100];
   char MGen[100];
}Movie[100];


int main()
{
    addFileM();
    return 0;
}


void addFileM()
{
    MovieF = fopen("d:\\movies.txt","r");
    for(int i=0;i<60;i++)
    {
        fscanf(MovieF, "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n",Movie[i].MID,Movie[i].MName,Movie[i].MYear,Movie[i].MDate,Movie[i].MIMDB,Movie[i].MGen);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<60;i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n\n",
                Movie[i].MID, Movie[i].MName, Movie[i].MYear,
                Movie[i].MDate, Movie[i].MIMDB, Movie[i].MGen);
    }
}
```

and output:

```
1
Toy
Story
1995
01-Jan-1995
http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?Toy%20Story%20(1995)

Animation|Children's|Comedy
2
GoldenEye
1995
01-Jan-1995
http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?GoldenEye%20(1995)

Action|Adventure|Thriller
3
Four
Rooms
1995
01-Jan-1995
```

As you can see "Toy Story" is stored in two different fields, and the genre data of the first movie is printed with the second movie.

Can you tell me what's the problem?

Comment: A) Please use complete words, not shorthand like "u" that may be confusing or unfamiliar to non-native English speakers. B) Can you explain where you think the problem is?

Comment: Your quoted output doesn't correspond to your input;

Comment: Is your program not running as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `%s` format specifier stops scanning whenever a *whitespece char* (a space, a tabulation, a newline and so on) is found.

That's why both *"Toy Story"* and *"Four Rooms"* are stored in two different fields of your struct, making your scanning literally "shift" positions (the genre field of the first movie will become the first field of the second movie and so on).

**Instead of using `%s` you could use `%[^\t]`.**

*Square brackets* format specifier scans a string containing a set of characters. But in case the `^` is present the character contained is avoided. So in this case it means *"store the string and stop when the first tab is found"*.

Even better: you can choose to store at most N characters by using the format `%N[^\t]`. Given the size of your destination array, just specify N as this size minus one (leaving the space for the string terminator).

Your `fscanf` will become something like:

```
fscanf(MovieF, "%49[^\t]%49[^\t]%49[^\t]%99[^\t]%99[^\t]\n",
       Movie[i].MID, Movie[i].MName, Movie[i].MYear,
       Movie[i].MDate, Movie[i].MIMDB, Movie[i].MGen);
```